# Visualising scalar and vector fields

Tags: electromagnetism, visualization

As I have been studying electromagnetic theory, I have always been lead to confusion when trying to visualise the fields. Fortunately, the electric and magnetic fields are vector fields and also along the propagation direction they provide a 3-Dimensional Coordinate system.

However, in general to visualise a N-dimensional field (I mean field depending on N coordinates), N+1 dimensions are necessary. For instance, in the case of 1D field $\phi(x)$, we can plot a graph $x$ vs $\phi(x)$.

But I am wondering if it is also possible to describe the fields using contours. To elaborate, if I have 2D field $\lambda(x,y)$ will it possible to visualise the field in 2D itself using contours (without actually plotting the variation of $\lambda(x,y)$ vs $x$ and  $y$).

Comment: Isn't this what contour plots are used for?

Comment: I am guessing so. But I am not sure how this works, if someone can give me a direction or example through this it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a scientific plotting program. The big names are Mathematica, Maple, Matlab. Those are good but cost money. There are plenty of free, open source options. Just poke around the Googles and you should find what you need. [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) comes to mind if you like to dabble in Python, but I'm sure there are GUI-based ones out there too.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) (a web-based, dumbed-down, but user-friendly version of Mathematica) might work for simple applications.

[Click here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contourplot+cos%28x%29*sin%28y%29) to see Wolfram Alpha code for a contour plot of $\cos(x)\sin(y)$. Here's the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to.  Think of topographical maps.  Contour lines closer together indicate steepness.  The only bugaboo is that you can't necessarily tell if the representation is rising or falling.  Some add little arrows to indicate that.

Comment: Or colors, if you don't want to use arrows.